# Facebook login api keeps reloading after login

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0

I'm having an issue with the facebook login api. The problem is I have no idea were to start, it was working perfectly and now it's not. I haven't changed any of it's code, I haven't changed anything that could interact with it. Please visit photoht.com and try and login with a facebook username. Login is succesfull but it isn't redirecting to the correct redirect url I have set on the server.

Comment: sorry, crystal ball is broken, come back next week

Comment: It's also not working in all of my sites. Looks like it's a Facebook issue. I'm also looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today. I had a message from Facebook Developers page.

> mysite.com currently has access to Graph API v2.2 which will reach the
>   end of its 2-year lifetime on 27 March, 2017. To ensure a smooth
>   transition, please migrate all calls to Graph API v2.3 or higher.

So it stopped working today.

I was using a very old PHP api. I'm assuming you are too. Just upgrade to the latest API: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk

There are some changes from the old API. Just follow the example code from github: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/tree/5.4/docs/examples

I just fixed mine. It is quite straightforward.